# Tracking down NSMutableArray "Request for large capacity"

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, debugging

When my app starts up, I've started getting a message in the log:

```
*** -[NSMutableArray initWithCapacity:]: Request for large capacity 9223372036854775808
```

I tried setting up a symbolic breakpoint for `-[NSMutableArray initWithCapacity:]`, but it doesn't trigger. How else can I figure out which call is causing this?

I'm in Xcode 4 on Lion, both updated fully.

**Update**

I tried also setting a symbolic breakpoint on `-[NSArray initWithCapacity:]`, which doesn't trigger.

I happened to stumble on the line of code causing this, which was (*inadvertantly*) setting a frame size with width of infinity. I'm keeping this post open though, because I would have liked a better way to find the line of code that caused this. I can still test suggestions, since I know how to reproduce the message.

Comment: Which value did you choose for the initial capacity to raise that error? Or did you choose `9223372036854775808` manually?

Comment: And it should be `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:capacity]` or `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:capacity]` for the convenience allocator.

Comment: How about a symbolic breakpoint on -[NSArray initWithCapacity:] ? (note, this uses NSArray instead of NSMutableArray)

Comment: Also, how are you creating all of your arrays? Do you have any initWithObjects:... lists that are not nil-terminated? Have you run the Xcode analyzer on your code?

Comment: I only use initWithCapacity twice for an array, and both times are with low counts. I never specify that insanely large number. Also, @bneely, I tried setting a breakpoint on the `NSArray` version as you suggested, but it didn't trigger either.

Comment: Note that `initWithCapacity:` is generally a waste of time;  it really doesn't improve much of anything performance wise.  Not that *that* knowledge helps address this question (which is why this is just a comment).

Comment: @bbum, see my update. I don't call it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a breakpoint on `CFLog()` and see if you can come up with a useful backtrace (that message is spewed by a call to `CFLog()`).   As long as there isn't much other logging going on, that should work.

Comment: I added a symbolic breakpoint on `CFLog()` and it never triggered.

Comment: Bummer.  Did you try it at the debugger prompt?  That'll often give some useful feedback.   Still, that your breakpoint on initWithCapacity: was never hit, is suspicious, too.   If you have a sample program that reproduces this, file a bug, attach the app binary and post the #.

Comment: Try what at the debugger prompt? Running the command that causes the message while stopped?

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by a negative value when initialising an array. Please check for both "[NSArray arrayWithCapacity:num]" and "[[NSArray alloc] initWithCapacity:num]"